# Keeping the modal open after canceling a prompt

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am working on a modal that has a cancel button but if the cancel button is pressed, the user will be prompted to choose if they want to go back or stay. When the confirmation comes up and you select 'Ok', the modal exits as it should but I noticed that if you select 'No, don't go back', it still exits the modal. Is there any workaround for this?

Here's my modal code:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Enter your Subject</h5>
</div>
<form action="/save-energystores" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Subject ID:</label>
<input type="text" name="subjectid" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" maxlength="6" style="text-transform:uppercase" required />
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Description:</label>
<textarea name="energystore_detail" class="form-control" id="message-text" required></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to quit?');">Close</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: At a guess, probs wants return false in your onclick after the confirm function

Comment: yes but how can I?